# Private docker container to release

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub, vapor

I am using a Dockerfile multistage configuration similar to the one below.

```
FROM swift:4.1

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN swift build --configuration release && mv `swift build -c release --show-bin-path` /build/bin

FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get install -y \
  libicu55 libxml2 libbsd0 libcurl3 libatomic1 wget  && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(wget -qO- https://apt.vapor.sh)"
RUN wget -q https://repo.vapor.codes/apt/keyring.gpg -O- | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install swift vapor -y

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /build/bin .
COPY --from=builder /build/lib/* /usr/lib/
EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ./Run serve -e prod -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

I am currently using this to deploy my service in a virtual server, which due to its low performance takes forever to build the project.

Is it a good practice, and possible, to build and upload to a private repo in docker hub the image result of the builder, so I can do it from my local machine?

Could I then just have the second step in my virtual server? That means:

```
FROM myPrivateImageBuiltLocally as image

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get install -y \
  libicu55 libxml2 libbsd0 libcurl3 libatomic1 wget  && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(wget -qO- https://apt.vapor.sh)"
RUN wget -q https://repo.vapor.codes/apt/keyring.gpg -O- | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install swift vapor -y

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /build/bin .
COPY --from=builder /build/lib/* /usr/lib/
EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ./Run serve -e prod -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.  You don't have to build it locally. You can use the automated build feature of dockerhub. It works like this.

1). Push the code to github/bitbucket
2). Create new image in dockerhub and map to the github repo

This will automatically build the image each time when you push a new commit to the github repo.

You can also see all the stats like build logs, Succss or failure, number of downloads etc...

ref: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/automated-build/#configure-automated-build-settings